# Не получается сделать связь "один ко многим" в laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, делаю проект на laravel и у меня возникла проблема со связью "один ко многим".У меня есть две модели User и Company. Хочу сделать чтобы все данные из USER привязывались к одной компании из KOMPANY.
Проблема в том, что следующий код выводит ошибку:

```
Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

```
<?php
    $company = Company::all();
    $users = User::all();
        
    foreach($company->users as $row){
        dd($row);
    }
```

*Что я сделал:*

Модели:

```
// USER
        
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
        
    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array<int, string>
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
        
    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
    *
    * @var array<int, string>
    */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
         'remember_token',
    ];
        
    /**
    * The attributes that should be cast.
    *
    * @var array<string, string>
    */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    public function companies() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
        
}
```

```
// COMPANY

class Company extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
        
    protected $fillable = [
        'company',
        'email',
        'logo',
        'addres',
        'points'
    ];
        
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
        
}
```

Миграция:

```
// users
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreignId('company_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('phoneNumber');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
        
    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка означает, что полученная методом all коллекция, такого свойства не имеет. Что логично. Динамическое свой свойство users принадлежит экземпляру классa Company. То есть  например такой код

```
$company1 = $companies[0]; 
foreach($company1->users as $user){}
```

Уже будет без ошибки. Конечно, при условии существования этих элементов.
И к слову связь hasMany в вашем случае буквально означает - одна компания может принадлежать многим пользователям. Подумайте, возможно вы не это планировали.